# Why won't my Python function be recursive/call itself?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I am making a String Rewriting Function that takes a string and rewrites it according to the rules in a dictionary. The code works perfectly fine once but I need it to call itself n times and print the 'nth' rewritten string. The code that works that I need to be recursive is:

```
S = "AB"
def srs_print(S, n, rules):
    '''
    A function that takes a dictionary as SRS rules and prints
    the output
    '''
    axiom = list(S)
    key =  []
    value = []
    output = ''

    for k in rules:
        #Inputs the keys of the rules dictionary into a new list
        key.append(k)
        #Inputs the value of the rules dictionary into a new list
        value.append(rules[k])

    for x in axiom:
        if x in key:
            axiomindex = key.index(x)
            output += value[axiomindex]
       else:
            output += x
    S = output
    return S
#j  =  srs_print(S, 5, {'A':'AB', 'B': 'A'})
#print(j)

#while len(range(n))  > 0:
#   S = srs_print(S, n, rules)
#   n = n-1
#print("The", n, "th rewrite is " )

#j = srs_print(S, 5, {'A':'AB', 'B': 'A'})
print(srs_print("A", 5, {'A':'AB', 'B': 'A'}))
```

This turns "A" into "AB" but I need it to put 'S' back into the function and run again 'n'times. As you can see, some of the commented code are lines I have tried to use but have failed.

I hope I've explained myself well enough.

Comment: Your function is not recursive because you never call `srs_print` inside `srs_print`. (Not that I think you need a recursive solution anyway. Why not just do something with `for x in range(n)`?)

Comment: Your function is not calling itself because it is not calling itself...

Comment: Failure to call function results in failure to run function. News at 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you pass "n" to the function as a way to count how many times you need to call it.

You could probably get away with enclosing the whole body of the function in a `for` or a `while`loop.
If you want it to be recursive anyway, here's how it could work:

You need to have "two" return statements for your function. One that returns the result (in your case, "S"), and another one, that returns `srs_print(S, n-1, rules)`
Ex:

```
if n > 0:
    return srs_print(S, n-1, rules)
else:
    return S
```

I suggest you take some time and read [this](http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php), to get a better understanding of what you *want* to do and whether or not it is what you *should* do.

Comment: Thank you, this is the actual answer I was looking for, I can't believe it was so simple! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You definitly don't need recursion here. First let's rewrite your function in a more pythonic way:

```
def srs_transform(string, rules):
    '''
    A function that takes a dictionary as SRS rules and prints
    the output
    '''

    # the short way:
    # return "".join(rules.get(letter, letter) for letter in string)


    # the long way
    output = []
    for letter in string:
        transformed = rules.get(letter, letter)
        output.append(transformed)
    return "".join(output)
```

Now we add a wrapper function that will take care of applying `srs_transform` a given number of times to it's arguments:

```
def srs_multi_transform(string, rules, times):
    output = string
    for x in range(times):
        output = srs_transform(output, rules)
    return output
```

And now we just have to call it:

```
print(srs_transform("A",  {'A':'AB', 'B': 'A'}, 5))

>> ABAABABAABAAB
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use a `for`-loop?

```
def srs_print(S, n, rules):
    for _ in range(n):
        S = ''.join(rules.get(x, x) for x in S)
    return S
```

Comment: I do really like this way, thank you but unfortunately it didn't fit the criteria my program had to

Comment: @PythonNoob: you have to learn, when recursion is useful. For this problem it is not.